# How can I have a horizontal scrollable element with bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, horizontal-scrolling

I have this:
[image]

This is what I have - and I don't want the icons to wrap on 2 lines.

I have:

```
<li class="list-group-item participants-grouping-li">
  <span class="avatar">....
</li>
```

And I tried:

```
.participants-grouping-li {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

But no dice. What am I missing? I'm focusing on making this mobile friendly, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below-mentioned snippet:

```
.participants-grouping-li {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```